# Handling AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, controllers, ajax, http-request

I have a class in my custom module that needs to handle various AJAX requests as well as a typical Magento request. I am using AngularJS on the front end.

Angular will submit request parameters in JSON format, so if you have a simple call such as:

```
$http.post('/mymodule/mycontroller/myaction', {param1: 'foo', param2: 'bar'});
```

You cannot simply use `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` to get param values. Instead you need to use `file_get_contents(php://input)` to get the raw input string which you can then `json_decode` or do whatever you need to to access the request params.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707431/http-post-using-angular-js

As I said, my custom class needs to handle both AJAX requests from Angular as well as normal Magento requests (or even AJAX requests from jQuery). The problem is handling the parameters in a consistent fashion.

**How can I normalize the request from Angular so that Magento still has access to `$this->getRequest()->getParams()`?**

Answer (score 2):

Use one action controller that has split functionality.  Have your ajax request pass something like '&ajax=1' as a parameter.  If this parameter exists then offer one functionality.  If this parameter isn't set then offer the second.

```
public function controllerAction(){
    $jsonContents = file_get_contents(php://input);
    if(!jsonContents){
       $jsonContents = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    }
    $contents = json_decode($jsonContents);
    if($contents['isAjax']==1){
        $response = $this->ajaxRequest();
    }else{
        $response = $this->normalRequest();
    }
}

protected function ajaxRequest(){
    ....
    //return response;
}

protected function normalRequest(){
    ....
    //return redirect (or whatever);
}
```

Nice and simple.

Answer (score 2):

I really wanted to keep things simple and I was not excited about using `file_get_contents('php://input')` all over the place. Here's what I used which should be all I need:

```
$ajaxRequest = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
foreach ($ajaxRequest as $key => $value) {
    $this->getRequest()->setPost($key, $value);
}
```

Comment: Oh, how does angular js compare -- in your opinion of course.

Comment: Not really part of the scope of the question, but for the task I am working on (a very complex ordering form with inputs bound all over the place) it is far superior to what I came up with in jQuery.

Comment: Of course not within these limited bounds, but friendly banter heeds no boundary!